# Batch File Choice Command Loops

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I've written a simple batch file with only a Choice command. The code is as follows:

```
Choice /C yn /M /t 5 "Do you want to continue"
If Errorlevel 2 Goto No


If Errorlevel 1 Goto Yes

Goto End
:No
Echo You selected No


Goto End
:Yes
Echo You selected Yes


:End
```

Problem is when I run it it doesn't wait for input .. It loops through and doesn't stop. I don't know what to do or why it doesn't work. I created a batch file at work with a choice command more complex than this and it works fine. But that file wouldn't work on my computer either.

Also if i type the choice command straight in cmd it works fine but batch file loops

Any suggestions? thanks

here is a link to a video that shows exactly what its doing http://youtu.be/4TkwlR7yMb8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/M` switch is for Message, you need to write the text after `/M`. You also need to include the `/D` switch (for Default), because you specified how long they have to make a selection with `/T`. The default option is the option that will be selected automatically if the user doesn't make a selection in, for your example, five seconds. The below example will automatically choose `n` at the end of time.

```
Choice /C yn /D n /T 5 /M "Do you want to continue"
```

The name of your batch file must not be the same as a command used inside your batch file. When you make a call to an executable (i.e. `choice`), cmd will look in the current directory for a file of that name before looking at directories in the `path` variable. So, because your batch file is called `choice.bat`, when you run the command `choice /c ...` you are actually making a call to the batch file itself, and not the `choice` command. Re-name your batch file.

Comment: I'll try but I'm still not sure why the one I made at work (syntax was correct ) didn't work on my computer but worked fine at work ... But my mistakes in this file are apparent thanks

Comment: Didnt work ... Your assessment on my syntax was correct thanks for that but it still loops. It even loops if I just put choice with no parameters

Comment: I am unable to replicate your issue. Is the code you have provided **exactly** what you are using?

Comment: What is the name of your batch file?

Comment: `choice.bat`is a likely candidate. :)

Comment: Haha yeah it is choice.bat I put the same code in a batch file at work and it works fine. This is weird . also did I mention that I can type it in cmd and it works fine ? Lol this is weird

Comment: You need to name the file something else. When you run the `choice` command you are just restarting your batch file.

Comment: I'm assuming when you did it at work, you didn't call the file choice.bat. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Lmfao that was the problem .. thanks a lot unclemeat ... that was so simple. I would say that is worse than for getting that dreaded semi colon in C haha .. thanks again guys

Comment: unclemeat how do i mark your comment as the answer? sorry i'm newish

Comment: Under the upvote / downvote arrows, there's a little tick that you should be able to click.

Comment: Note that depending of the operating system, the script will work or not. On Windows XP, the "choice" command is not included so it can produce a  continuous loop. Even if you add a CHOICE command from DOS, you can have a new problem because then parameter /M is not recognized.